# injectJavaScript can't set object in production, but in development works find

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm making webview app and trying to set empty location object to web by using injectJavaScript in expo app.

I've test this app in development, it works well which when I tried `alert(window.ReactNativeApp.location)` it returns `{}` but in production it returns `undefined` why?

Anyone can help on this?

```js
const App = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState<Location.LocationObject>()
  const webViewRef = useRef<WebView>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    ;(async () => {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()

      if (status !== Location.PermissionStatus.GRANTED) {
        return
      }

      try {
        const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
          accuracy: Location.LocationAccuracy.Highest,
        })

        setLocation(location)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    })()

    Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
  }, [])
  
  const INJECT_LOCATION = /*javascript*/ `
    window.ReactNativeApp = {
      location: {}
    }
  `

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!location) {
      return
    }

    webViewRef?.current?.injectJavaScript(INJECT_LOCATION)
  }, [location])

  return (
    <WebView
      ref={webViewRef}
      injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={`
        window.onerror = function(message, sourcefile, lineno, colno, error) {
          alert("Message: " + message + " - Source: " + sourcefile + " Line: " + lineno + ":" + colno);
          return true;
        };
        true;
      `}
      style={styles.container}
      source={{ uri: 'http://cocoboli.com/main' }}
      onMessage={(event) => {}}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  webViewRef?.current?.injectJavaScript(INJECT_LOCATION)
}, 3000)
```

setTimeout is the key!!